# Fail to start jenkins from browser

Tags: jenkins

I am really new to jenkins.
Today i installed and tried to play around. Sure I am missing a key.

My environment:
java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (rhel-1.49.1.11.4.el6_3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

tomcat6

CentOS 6.3

From the command line, I run the jenkins.war as and the results are as following

## java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8082 --ajp13Port=-1

```
Running from: /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:55 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jenkins home directory: /home/admin/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:56 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: HTTP Listener started: port=8082
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:56 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running: controlPort=disabled
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:56 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:57 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:57 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:57 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:57 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Sep 20, 2012 1:32:57 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Sep 20, 2012 1:33:00 PM org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils$BouncyCastleRegistration run
INFO: Trying to register BouncyCastle as a JCE provider
Sep 20, 2012 1:33:00 PM org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils$BouncyCastleRegistration run
INFO: Registration succeeded
Sep 20, 2012 1:33:00 PM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 34921
Sep 20, 2012 1:33:01 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Sep 20, 2012 1:33:01 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 59382
Sep 20, 2012 1:33:01 PM hudson.WebAppMain$2 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

So I thought everything was fine.

From the browser, none of this is working

```
http://IP:8080/jenkins
http://IP:8082/jenkins
```

Could someone help me about this?

Best regards,
Adjeiifo

Answer (score 2):

Why are you adding the /jenkins at the end? http://:8082 should be enought
Furthermore, have you checked your firewall,proxy or your antivirus? 
Can you access locally your installation by typing localhost:8082 in your browser? If yes then one of the above or some other network configuration may be the problem

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it has something to do with the firewall and network configuration. When I run /etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables stop, it works fine. I am going to investigate the configuration and let you know. Thanks
Adjeiinfo

Comment: If you find the solution and my answer was helpful please accept it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the firewall

may be it is necessary to disable the para- fire on some harbor harbor example : 8080
the Lunix orders

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```

the command is tested on CentOS on a VM

Answer (score -1):

Use the installer and repair the Jenkins service.

In case of Windows, please use the downloaded Zip and extract the msi installer file.

Double click on that and repair the jenkins installation on your system